# Options for Stolen Phone

Tags: security, lost-phone

With an iPhone, you tie your phone to an iCloud account - it happens at the bootloader level. If your phone gets stolen, the thief can't do anything until the previous owner releases the phone from his/her iCloud account.

I have a co-worker who had his iPhone stolen. "Later" he got contacted by the new owner who wanted to use the phone. Obviously, co worker wouldn't do this - that's what you get for buying a stolen phone. The new owner can't do anything with the phone except send it back or break it (he took option two, unfortunately).

I see plenty of options that allow you to track, remote wipe, lock, activate alarm, etc... You can encrypt the device and/or sd...

But what is stopping the next person from flashing or factory resetting the phone, formatting the encrypted SD and using both of those anyways?

So my question is...Are there any standard options that will stop the phone from being reformatted or is that something that's up to the phone manufacturer? I don't want to [remotely brick](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19444/remotely-brick-a-stolen-phone) my phone if it gets stolen - I want to stop it from being used by anyone but me - full stop.

Comment: There are options to require a password to factory reset phones, But TBH that wouldn't stop someone who is determined enough, You could always install a custom recovery and flash a rom, as far as I know. But I was reading a while back that a lot of carriers are starting to record stolen IMEI numbers on phones and blacklisting them from being activated. As far as I remember anyway.

Comment: A good starting point for finding an answer on your issue is our [lost-phone tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/lost-phone/info). You've already used this tag here (correctly); you might have missed that most of our tags have a wiki associated often containing first-aid and central hints on the topic ;)

Comment: @jer3my Stolen IMEI lists aren't 100% like iPhone iCloud lock... friends iPhone went to Russia (Broken and angry "new" owner) and then to some other country. I doubt those carriers go through those measures. I could be wrong.

Comment: @Izzy I hadn't seen that, and it's good info - but mostly what I already basically know (for example, I have the Avast app installed with root options enabled - hide app, bring back app if uninstalled, etc). But that information doesn't quite answer if Android (Either via Google or individual Carriers) can say THIS phone is locked to THIS account until the currently tagged owner says otherwise - and formatting won't change that.

Comment: @WernerCD ahh good point about phones leaving the country. But yeah Android doesn't have anything like the Apple lock. Not that I know of at least.